# Getting hooks error while running test on Python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Getting hooks error while running test on Python with selenium

Individually test are running fine but on running collete

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "D:\voicegaincode\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 271, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "D:\voicegaincode\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 324, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "D:\voicegaincode\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 493, in __call_
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "D:\voicegaincode\voicegain\venv\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 115, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>     raise PluginValidationError(
INTERNALERROR> pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html_results_table_header' in plugin <module 'conftest' from 'D:\\voicegaincode\\voicegain\\conftest.py'>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJGpp.png)

```
pytest -m others -v --html-report=./report/report.html

pytest -m console -v --html-report=./report/report.html

pytest -m transcribe -v --html-report=./report/report.html
```

Used this command